# "ValueError: Unknown event source" with Zappa and SQS events to trigger lambda

Tags: python, flask, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, python-zappa

I am  trying to set up SQS events' trigger for my serverless python's flask app. Once I try to **deploy** using **Zappa** it will give me this message:

```
Oh no! An error occurred! :(

==============

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "...\venv\lib\site-packages\zappa\core.py", line 2613, in unschedule_events
    self.boto_session
  File "...\venv\lib\site-packages\zappa\utilities.py", line 317, in remove_event_source
    event_source_obj, ctx, funk = get_event_source(event_source, lambda_arn, target_function, boto_session, dry=False)
  File "...\venv\lib\site-packages\zappa\utilities.py", line 256, in get_event_source
    raise ValueError('Unknown event source: {0}'.format(arn))
ValueError: Unknown event source: arn:aws:sqs:MY_QUEUE

==============
```

Here is the relevant information in my *zappa_settings.json*

```
"dev_events": {
"debug": true,
"log_level": "DEBUG",
"app_function": "application.app",
"aws_region": ...,
"profile_name": "default",
"project_name": ..,
"runtime": "python3.6",
"s3_bucket": ...,
"timeout_seconds": 30,
"keep_warm": false,
"keep_warm_expression": "rate(5 minutes)",
"memory_size": 256,
"manage_roles": true,
"use_precompiled_packages": true,
"environment_variables": {
  ...
},
"aws_environment_variables ": {
  ...
},
"events": [
  {
    "function": "application.process_simulation_paths_queue",
    "event_source": {
      "arn": "arn:aws:sqs:MY_QUEUE",
      "batch_size": 10,
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
],
"exclude": [
  ...
]
}
```

I already created my SQS's queue with the right name and copied its ARN, then I followed the format documented in the [issue](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/issues/1613) and this [PR](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/pull/1617/files) to configure my *zappa_settings.json*

Comment: What version of Zappa are you using? Is it possible you've got an old version from before the SQS support was added?

Comment: @MattHealy that is exactly what happened, been a while since I last updated Zappa, What is the minimum required version of Zappa for this feature?

Comment: Looks like you need 0.47.0 according to https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0470

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need, at a minimum, version 0.47.0 of Zappa to use SQS as event sources:

https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0470